# Set up IIS on Windows 7 Starter

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, windows-7

I'm trying to set up IIS on Windows 7 starter for a client.  I have it mostly working, however, it seems like my ajax requests aren't working.  'I tried to set it up through the "Add or Remove Windows Features" menu but "Web Management Tools" isn't included in the submenu.  Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong or an alternative method?  Thanks.

***Edit***

**Solution**
I ended up using UltiDev's Cassini server to solve this issue.  It works with telerik and all of my ajax works.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended up using UltiDev's Cassini server to solve this issue. It works with telerik and all of my ajax works. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 Home Premium is the edition that starts including those tools. You could use [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb) instead.

Comment: Is this a competent version of IIS?

Comment: @mrK: It is the same as IIS 7.5 you'd find built into Windows 7, just with some features missing (Like Dynamic Content Compression). You shouldn't have any problems using it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  None of the moving controls on the page move.  However, when I use the web.config that I want, I get an error with the scriptResourceHandler section.  I removed it but the ajax controls don't work.  If this is the problem, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/) shows how to install IIS in Win 7 (I believe it works in Starter as well). In addition, if you install [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/WebMatrix), I believe you get IIS 7.5 with it that would work also. What about your AJAX requests isn't working?

Comment: I have telerik controls included on the page that I'm creating.  For example, i have a radmenu at the top.  However, when I scroll over one of the menu items, it doesn't drop down.

Comment: Did you get the Telerik stuff working? If not, did you try this? http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-troubleshooting-production-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Many tools are not available to the windows 7 starter edition.

Comment: Thats the problem I seem to be running into.  Any good alternatives?